# How can I make my discord bot reply to a message when it contains a specific letter/character?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So basically, I want my bot to reply to people who input commands for other bots, for example when they type -p(play) (insert song here)
I don't want my bot to play a song but instead I want it to reply to them just as when people like to give their thoughts on someone's opinion with a variety of answers.
I already input a command where it replies to people when they write $w but what I want is for my bot to reply when they put something else after $w.

```
const replies = [
    "nice", "I like it", "We have the same tastes", "lucky!", "I wish I were you",
]

client.on("message", gotMessage);

async function gotMessage(msg) {

    if (msg.content === "$w"){
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length);
        msg.channel.send(replies[index]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to check if a word is in the message.
To do so you can use the `String.includes()`.

```
if (msg.content.includes("$w"){
    //do stuff
}
```

EDIT:

You could also check if the message starts with it

````
if(msg.content.startsWith("$w")){
//do stuff
}```
````